# In libGDX is there a JavaFX's PathTransition equivalent?

Tags: java, javafx, libgdx

We are in the middle of transitioning from JavaFX to libGDX.  Wondering if there is an equivalent to [PathTransition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html) in libGDX.

What is specifically awesome about PathTransition is that it rotates your Node accordingly while it traverses through the Path.  What sucks about PathTransition is that you need to calculate the speed yourself, that is to say that you only provide how long it will take to finish the traversal but you need to figure out how long the path is so that you can set the appropriate duration.

Was hoping libGDX had something similar or better yet an improved version of PathTransition.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example you posted, I don't think that there is a *direct* equivalent in libGDX, but we can make one.

libGDX comes with a scene graph called [Scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) which allows you to apply actions to Actors or groups of Actors. There are a bunch of actions built in (MoveTo, RotateBy) and you can execute them in parallel to each other or sequentially. You can also apply the [Interpolation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interpolation) classes for tweening.

libGDX also comes with a [Path](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Path-interface-&-Splines) interface, but as of 1.9.4 there isn't a PathAction, but that doesn't mean you can't build something like the one below:

```
package tech.otter.gdxsandbox.demos;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.CatmullRomSpline;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Path;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Action;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

public class PathDemo extends Demo {
    private ShapeRenderer sr;
    private Stage stage;

    public PathDemo() {
        super("Action Demo");
        stage = new Stage();
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        sr = new ShapeRenderer();
        Actor ourCircle = new SimpleCircleActor(sr, 10f);
        stage.addActor(ourCircle);

        ourCircle.addAction(new PathAction(5f, 50f, 50f, 100f, 60f, 300f, 200f, 100f, 400f));
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        sr.setAutoShapeType(true);
        sr.begin();
        sr.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
        sr.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        sr.dispose();
    }

    private class SimpleCircleActor extends Actor {
        private ShapeRenderer renderer;
        private float radius;

        public SimpleCircleActor(ShapeRenderer renderer, float radius) {
            this.renderer = renderer;
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        /**
         * Assumes something outside is setting the ShapeRenderer type/begin/end.
         * Don't do this at home, kids.
         */
        @Override
        public void draw(Batch batch, float delta) {
            renderer.circle(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.radius);
        }
    }

    private class PathAction extends Action {
        private Path<Vector2> path;
        private float current;
        private float duration;
        public PathAction(float duration, float... coordinates) {
            this.duration = duration;
            this.current = 0;

            Vector2[] dataSet = new Vector2[coordinates.length / 2];
            for(int i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
                dataSet[i] = new Vector2(coordinates[2*i], coordinates[2*i+1]);
            }
            this.path = new CatmullRomSpline<Vector2>(dataSet, true);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean act(float delta) {
            if(duration == current) return true; // The action has already completed.

            if(current + delta >= duration) {
                current = duration;
            } else {
                current += delta;
            }

            Vector2 out = new Vector2(); // Get our position on the path.
            this.path.valueAt(out, current / duration);
            this.actor.setPosition(out.x, out.y);

            return duration == current; // Return whether we are now complete.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to easily run your example. Could you provide the `Demo` class source code, or are their two many dependencies?

Comment: It's part of a little sandbox I've put together which is on github: https://github.com/madigan/gdx-sandbox

Comment: However, it's worth noting that pretty much everything that PathDemo.java is doing could be copy and pasted into a class extending Game or implementing ApplicationListener and it would work with a little tweaking.

Comment: Thanks a lot John.  Messing with it now.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working.  The class below creates an `Action` instance, `SequenceAction` to be exact.  The `Action` it creates will traverse an `Actor` through the points the user provides.  It takes into account speed, duration, offsetting the `Actor`'s position on the path, rotating the `Actor`, and even indenting the `Actor` when leaving and coming into the screen.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.SequenceAction;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author jmart
 */
public class PathActionMaker {

    private final float[][] points;
    private float speed = 0;
    private final float rotationSpeed = 600;
    private float[] screenSize;

    /**
     *
     * @param points - all the path points that must be traversed
     * @param duration - how long it should take to traverse the path points
     * @param screenSize - the size of the screen
     */
    public PathActionMaker(float[][] points, float duration, float[] screenSize) {
        this.points = points;
        this.speed = getSpeed(points, duration);
        this.screenSize = screenSize;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param speed - the speed at which the Actor should move traverse through
     * all the points
     * @param points - all the path points that must be traversed
     * @param screenSize - the size of the screen
     */
    public PathActionMaker(float speed, float[][] points, float[] screenSize) {
        this.points = points;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.screenSize = screenSize;
    }

    /**
     * The offsets are used to allow centering of an actor on the provided
     * points.
     *
     * @param xOffset
     * @param yOffset
     * @param offScreenIndent number of pixels to move the actor out of screen
     * when entering and leaving
     * @return
     */
    public SequenceAction getAction(float xOffset, float yOffset, float offScreenIndent) {
        float[] prev = null;
        float prevTheta = 0;
        int i = 0;
        SequenceAction seqAction = Actions.sequence();
        boolean firstRotation = true;
        float[][] fixedPoints = getOffSetFixedPoints(points, xOffset, yOffset, offScreenIndent);
        for (float[] point : fixedPoints) {
            float[] p = point;
            if (prev == null) {
                seqAction.addAction(Actions.moveTo(p[0], p[1]));
            } else {
                float dist = MathUtils.getDistance(prev[0], prev[1], p[0], p[1]);
                float time = dist / speed;
                float theta = MathUtils.angle(prev[0], prev[1], p[0], p[1]) + 90;
                if (theta > 360) {
                    theta -= 360;
                }
                float dTheta = Math.abs(prevTheta - theta);
                float rotateDuration = dTheta / rotationSpeed;
                // the first rotation should be immediate.
                if (firstRotation) {
                    firstRotation = false;
                    seqAction.addAction(Actions.parallel(
                            Actions.moveTo(p[0], p[1], time),
                            Actions.rotateTo(theta)));//...rotation duration is 0, aka immediate
                } else {
                    seqAction.addAction(Actions.parallel(
                            Actions.moveTo(p[0], p[1], time),
                            Actions.rotateTo(theta, rotateDuration)));
                }
                prevTheta = theta;
            }
            prev = p;
        }
        return seqAction;
    }

    public float[][] getOffSetFixedPoints(float[][] points, float xOffset, float yOffset, float offScreenIndent) {
        List<Float[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

        //apply offset indent at beginning of path
        float[] p1 = points[0];
        float[] p2 = points[1];
        float slope = (p1[1] - p2[1]) / (p1[0] - p2[0]);
        float c = p1[1] - slope * p1[0];

        if (p1[0] == 0) {
            float x = -offScreenIndent;
            float y = slope * x + c;
            list.add(new Float[]{x - xOffset, y - yOffset});
        } else if (p1[0] == screenSize[0]) {
            float x = screenSize[0] + offScreenIndent;
            float y = slope * x + c;
            list.add(new Float[]{x - xOffset, y - yOffset});
        } else if (p1[1] == 0) {
            float y = -offScreenIndent;
            float x = (y - c) / slope;
            list.add(new Float[]{x - xOffset, y - yOffset});
        } else if (p1[1] == screenSize[1]) {
            float y = screenSize[1] + offScreenIndent;
            float x = (y - c) / slope;
            list.add(new Float[]{x - xOffset, y - yOffset});
        }

        //apply the remaining points
        for (float[] point : points) {
            float[] p = {point[0] - xOffset, point[1] - yOffset};
            addPointToList(p, list);
        }

        //apply offscreen indent at end of path
        float[] p4 = points[points.length - 1];
        float[] p3 = points[points.length - 2];
        slope = (p3[1] - p4[1]) / (p3[0] - p4[0]);
        c = p3[1] - slope * p3[0];

        if (p4[0] <= 0) {
            float x = -offScreenIndent;
            float y = slope * x + c;
            list.add(new Float[]{x - xOffset, y - yOffset});
        } else if (p4[0] >= screenSize[0]) {
            float x = screenSize[0] + offScreenIndent;
            float y = slope * x + c;
            list.add(new Float[]{x - xOffset, y - yOffset});
        } else if (p4[1] <= 0) {
            float y = -offScreenIndent;
            float x = (y - c) / slope;
            list.add(new Float[]{x - xOffset, y - yOffset});
        } else if (p4[1] >= screenSize[1]) {
            float y = screenSize[1] + offScreenIndent;
            float x = (y - c) / slope;
            list.add(new Float[]{x - xOffset, y - yOffset});
        }

        //convert list to float[][]
        float[][] rv = new float[list.size()][];
        int i = 0;
        for (Float[] p : list) {
            float[] j = new float[2];
            j[0] = p[0];
            j[1] = p[1];
            rv[i++] = j;
        }
        return rv;
    }

    private static void addPointToList(float[] point, List<Float[]> list) {
        list.add(new Float[]{point[0], point[1]});
    }

    private float getSpeed(float[][] points, float duration) {
        //speed = distance/time
        float distance = MathUtils.getDistance(points);
        return distance / duration;
    }

}
```